# asp.net custom validator not firing.

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateProductID(sender, args)
{
    var productID = document.getElementById('<%=txtProductID.ClientID%>').value;
    var productType = document.getElementById('<%=rcbProduct.ClientID%>').value;

    if (productID != "" && productID == "") {
        args.isValid = false;
    }
}
```

i have this custom validation to validate 2 contorls, ProductType should be selected if productID is entered.

here is the aspx code

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true" 
                                                       ErrorMessage="please select a Product" 
                                                       ClientValidationFunction="ValidateProductID"
                                                       ControlToValidate ="txtProductID"
                                                       Display = "Dynamic">
                                  </asp:CustomValidator>
```

the event is not firing, am i missing something ??

Comment: are you missing a validation group by any chance?

Comment: How did you create the `txtProductID` control and your submit/action button?

Comment: '<asp:TextBox ID="txtProductID" runat="server" Width="110"></asp:TextBox></td>'

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton12" runat="server" CommandName="SearchWorkFlow" CssClass="tile-submodule submod-color shadow-submodule" OnClick="PageAction">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (productID != "" && productID == "")
```

was wrong (typo) it should be

```
 if (productID != "" && productType == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the ControlToValidate blank.

> Like all the other validation controls (besides
>   RequiredFieldValidator), it is considered valid if the input field is
>   blank.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx